# Live CD Doesn't see Hard Drive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install 18.04 as a dual boot with Windows 10. I've been able to shrink the Windows partition using it's Disk Management tool and have 80 gigs of unallocated space for Ubuntu. I've also created a bootable USB stick but when I run the installer, the stick is the only drive that shows up. I've been googling for fixes but haven't had any success. This is the output of fdisk, as I saw suggested in a lot of posts:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1864450048 bytes, 3641504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 86.9 MiB, 91099136 bytes, 177928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

(There are 7 of these /dev/loop entries in total, I left the rest out to save space. I can update if they're important)

Disk /dev/sda: 28.9 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0274c341

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 60555263 60553216 28.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

And this is the output of parted:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo parted -l
Model:  Patriot Memory (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 31.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  31.0GB  31.0GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

The laptop is a Dell XPS 13. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been asked in many places.  You need to change SSD controller setting in BIOS from RAID to AHCI, or Linux won't find it.

But the downside is that you need to fix or re-install your Windows in AHCI mode.

Comment: Just install AHCI drivers in Windows *before* changing modes.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Somehow I never came across that while searching for a solution. I now have a working dual boot setup.

Comment: The SSD controller setting in point can be labelled as 'SATA mode' in your Boot Manager; is that correct?