# Ubuntu Live USB cannot see one partitions of my hard drive partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, partitioning, live-usb

I migrated from Linux Mint after some problem with NVIDIA, wifi and login loop, to Ubuntu, but with doing this site instruction to save my home folder I have a gain those problems which I have asked some of them [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187330/nvidia-driver-problem-after-migration-to-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1#comment1984569_1187330) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187893/problem-with-installing-ubuntu-18-04-dual-boot-and-separate-home-folder-nvidia):

[**NVIDIA driver problem after migration to Ubuntu 18.04**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187330/nvidia-driver-problem-after-migration-to-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1#comment1984569_1187330)

[**Problem with installing Ubuntu 18.04 (dual boot and separate home folder, NVIDIA graphic card miscellaneous),but run Ubuntu from USB works fine**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187893/problem-with-installing-ubuntu-18-04-dual-boot-and-separate-home-folder-nvidia)

in that situation Ubuntu stuck in login loop and after that I must press `ctr+alt+f3` and run `sudo startX` by setting NVIDIA to `xconf...` option and doing `sudo apt purge nvidia*` (before pseudo startx`). to have access to low resolution screen and not installed correctly Intel driver which is annoying to work with. for some more info you could see [my previous  question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187330/nvidia-driver-problem-after-migration-to-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1#comment1984569_1187330).

I have tried to install Ubuntu from live USB and trying to format `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda7` and setting them to `/home/` and `/` Respectively  but during instillation it got some error and for new restarting from live USB it stuck in installation process and now it can not show my hard drives for first time and after running `sudo fdisk -l` it showed my hard partitions except `/dev/sda7` as you can see here:

[image]

so the output of the `sudo fdisk -l` is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.9 GiB, 1987817472 bytes, 3882456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 88.5 MiB, 92778496 bytes, 181208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 54.4 MiB, 57069568 bytes, 111464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 42.8 MiB, 44879872 bytes, 87656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 149.9 MiB, 157184000 bytes, 307000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 4 MiB, 4218880 bytes, 8240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 14.8 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 1008 KiB, 1032192 bytes, 2016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x395636f5

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        420100094 3581657005 3161556912   1.5T  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda2  *    3581657088 3907028991  325371904 155.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3             2048  420098047  420096000 200.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5        840198144 2373611519 1533413376 731.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       2373613568 3581657005 1208043438   576G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7        420100096  840198143  420098048 200.3G 83 Linux

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 8027897856 bytes, 15679488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5092863d

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 4067999 4068000    2G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       3989132 3994059    4928  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disk /dev/loop8: 3.7 MiB, 3825664 bytes, 7472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

So what do you suggest doing according this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086979/live-cd-doesnt-see-hard-drive):

> This has been asked in many places. You need to change SSD controller
>   setting in BIOS from RAID to AHCI, or Linux won't find it.
>
> But the downside is that you need to fix or re-install your Windows in
>   AHCI mode.

Why one of partitions don't shown after using `fdisk` command?, Also after doing this is my dual boot deleted or not? if yes how can recover again it to have access to win and Ubuntu like before migration with new Ubuntu OS?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Anytime you have an abnormal shutdown which it seems you did in closing install in middle, you may need fsck to repair partition. Run this on your sda7 & sda3, example shows using sdb1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, i will check it now.

Comment: So i means to run `sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda7` or `sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sdb1` based of [above line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789) or do `sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda1` ? what is different of `sda` with `sdb`?

Comment: Drives are sda, sdb, sdc, etc. Partitions are then the numbers after the drive, like sda1, sda2, sdb1, sdb2, etc. The example is just for sdb1 (first partition on second drive), you do not even have a sdb drive? Your parted list should show what drives & partitions you have. And fsck can only run on ext2, ext3, or ext4 formatted partitions. The two commands are a version that does not require you to say y (yes) on an error and command that will ask you y, but auto answers so it can run without lots of y's, if needed.