# umount -f works but target is busy (Also GParted can not check it successfully)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, gparted

Try to `umount -f  /dev/sda7` as said here to do `sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda7` based of comment of [my previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188036/ubuntu-live-usb-cannot-see-one-partitions-of-my-hard-drive-partitions?noredirect=1#comment1985928_1188036) i get this error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# umount -f  /dev/sda7
umount: /dev/sda7: not mounted.
root@ubuntu:~# sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda7
/dev/sda7 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.


root@ubuntu:~# dmsetup ls
No devices found
```

also cannot to checked successfully by GParted as could be seen here:

[image]

[image]

Also based of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878707/how-to-unmount-a-busy-device) i get no output!!:

> If possible, let's locate/identify the busy the process, kill the
>   process and then unmount the samba share to minimize damage.
>
> ```
> lsof | grep '<mountpoint of /dev/sda1>' (or whatever the mounted device is)
>
> pkill target_process (kills busy proc. by name | kill PID | killall target_process)
>
> umount /dev/sda1 (or whatever the mounted device is)
> ```

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/999/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
root@ubuntu:~# lsof | grep /dev/sda7
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/999/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Also can not format `/dev/sda7` by GParted :

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your `/etc/fstab` and the results of `lsblk` (add to your question).

Comment: Thanks @ajgringo619 but i don't waited for ... And rebooted again with ubuntu live usb and dont have this problem again. But don't know what was created that problem.

Comment: I suggest to try discover which process make the /dev is busy try # sudo fuser -vm /dev/sda7